# Block scrolling when popover is opened

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm not sure how to make the 'Popover' component of Material UI remain fixed on the screen when I open it. Because when I open the popover (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) It's not blocking the scroll and the box that appears after clicking is moving along the entire page. I don't want to keep the scroll bar visible while popover is open.

I'm using the latest version.

Image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfrmm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to body element and remove it on close :) Tho its a weird behavior in docs as in source code there is no such thing, yet it happens